# next-auth middleware not redirecting to signin page

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I have the simplest setup and next-auth still is not redirecting me to the signin page when there is no session/token or anything.

```js
// src/app/middleware.ts    
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
```

https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#basic-usage

> The most simple usage is when you want to require authentication for your entire site. You can add a middleware.js file with the following:

That I did!

```js
// src/app/layout.tsx
export default async function RootLayout({
    children,
}: RootLayoutProps) {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)

    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <SessionProvider session={session}>
                <body>
                    {children}
                </body>
            </SessionProvider>
        </html>
    )
}
```

The route:

```js
// src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import authOptions from '@/lib/auth-options';

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

And the auth options:

```js
import { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    debug: true,
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. "Sign in with...")
            name: "Credentials",
            // `credentials` is used to generate a form on the sign in page.
            // You can specify which fields should be submitted, by adding keys to the `credentials` object.
            // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
            // You can pass any HTML attribute to the <input> tag through the object.
            credentials: {
                email: {
                    label: "Email",
                    type: "text",
                    placeholder: "email@vansite.eu"
                },
                password: {
                    label: "Password",
                    type: "password"
                }
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
                const user = {
                    id: "1", name: "J Smith",
                    email: "jsmith@example.com"
                }

                if (user) {
                    // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
                    return user
                } else {
                    // If you return null then an error will be displayed advising the user to check their details.
                    return null

                    // You can also Reject this callback with an Error thus the user will be sent to the error page with the error message as a query parameter
                }
            }
        })
    ]
}

export default authOptions;
```

I expect that when I visit `http://localhost:3000` that I'm redirected to `http://localhost/api/auth/signin`. But that is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Yea It was kind of not clear what should be added to options file and to providers as well. I fixed this buy using in `middleware.ts`.

Also for my `authOptions` file looks like this:

```js
import { type NextRequestWithAuth, withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';
const middleware = async (request: NextRequestWithAuth) => {
    // your middleware function logic
};
export const config = {
    matcher: ['/'],
};
export default withAuth(middleware);
```

Very important here to have config const to be exported as well from what i find out/ Without config it not work for me.
And this is my `authOptions.ts` file where you can see that I am using custom login page

```js
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: 'credentials',
            name: 'credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: { label: 'Email', type: 'text' },
                password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
            },
            authorize: async (credentials, req) => {
                if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) return null;

                const user: User | null = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                    where: {
                        email: credentials.email,
                    },
                });

                if (!user) return null;

                const doesPasswordMatch = await compare(
                    credentials.password,
                    user.hashedPassword
                );

                if (!doesPasswordMatch) return null;
                console.log({ user }, { credentials }, { req });
                return user;
            },
        }),
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login',
    },
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    callbacks: {},
};
```

Important here as well secret variable name `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` only like this and no options. Without this name it will not work.
Also my `route.ts` file from `src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authOptions } from './authOptions';
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```